# PyQt: Add icon to right side of QListWidget item

Tags: qt, pyqt, icons, qlistwidget

In a QlistWidget, When using `listItem.setIcon(qIcon)` the icon is put on the left of the list item. How can I make it show up on the right as shown below?

[image]

Also another question. How can I remove the icon from the item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done quite easily with a simple custom item-delegate:

```python
class ItemDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        option.decorationPosition = QtGui.QStyleOptionViewItem.Right
        super(ItemDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.delegate = ItemDelegate()
        self.listWidget.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)
```

To remove an icon from an item, just set it to a null `QIcon`:

```
listItem.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon())
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

For this you will need to provide your own item delegate that draws the item data like you want.

See `QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegate()`.

You can likely use `QStyledItemDelegate` as your base class and let its `paint()` handle all aspects other than the `Qt::DecorationRole` (the icon) and draw that yourself.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer. I haven't created a custom delegate before so I'm not sure how to approach it in PyQt, is there like a reference I can take a look?

Comment: I haven't used PyQt myself, but my guess is that you use the standard Python subclassing syntax and then overwrite the paint method with a function signature like this `def paint(self, painter, option, index):`

Comment: I think I found a good example. http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/pyqt4-qitemdelegate-example-with/ But the thing is my list widget is created in Qt Designer, I'm not sure how I can seamlessly replace it with the delegate version!

Comment: You don't need to replace the view, you only need to create an object of your delegate class and the call `setItemDelegate()` on the view object.
If you look at the example you linked then the line `lv = QListView()` is basically what the code generated from designer's file will have done, the lines about creating and setting the delegate also apply to you